# OAuth2 Client (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on

I'm creating a single sign-on (SSO) service using Python, Django, Django Rest Framework and Django OAuth Toolkit (https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit). The SSO service will be a central, stand-alone application providing user identity services (granting access to user information as an OAuth2 Protected Resource).

Django OAuth Toolkit  helps to implement the OAuth2 Authorisation Server. Is there a similarly good quality Django or Python library that can help in implementing the OAuth2 Client (see following diagram snippet taken from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2)?

```
+--------+                               +---------------+
|        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
|        |                               |     Owner     |
|        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
|        |                               +---------------+
|        |
|        |                               +---------------+
|        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
| Client |                               |     Server    |
|        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
|        |                               +---------------+
|        |
|        |                               +---------------+
|        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
|        |                               |     Server    |
|        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
+--------+                               +---------------+
```

(I expect the main use case wouldn't be a problem to implement myself, but if a good library provides handling of corner cases, errors, retries and is well tested, then it would be a shame to reinvent.)

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coming back to answer my own question some time after finding and implementing a solution...

My chosen approach was to read the relevant RFCs ([The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
and [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)) and implement a solution with the help of the [requests-oauthlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-oauthlib) [OAuth-2 workflow](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html).

A high-level breakdown of the resulting Django app that I wrote involved creating:

- URL routing for login, login-callback and logout
- Accompanying views to process requests from those URLs.
- An OAuth2 authentication backend.
- Middleware to enforce authentication on views that require it.

The Django app was implemented as a pip-installable stand-alone client that could be used by systems that required a single sign-on.

An OAuth-2 authorization server, implemented with the help of [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-oauth-toolkit), provided the hub for my single sign-on infrastructure.

Comment: I'm quite interested by your solution. Could you link to your "pip-installable stand-alone client" please?

Comment: @Guts: Unfortunately, the code that I wrote is not open source (it was written for a client), so I can't link to it. My answer, above, is a fair description of what is required. Perhaps you could post a reply here if you yourself write an open source solution. I would happily change the accepted answer to a correct answer with associated working source code.